# DDEV http://projectname.ddev.local doesn't work on Windows 10 while http://127.0.0.1:randomport does work

Tags: windows-10, localhost, drupal-8, ddev

Ddev started succesfully my project and tells me "project can be reached at http://example.ddev.local https://example.ddev.local, http://127.0.01:32771"

I read in config.yaml

```
# name: <projectname> # Name of the project, automatically provides
#   http://projectname.ddev.local and https://projectname.ddev.local
```

But my project can only be succesfully reached at http://127.0.01:32771 instead automatically provinding the http://projectname.ddev.local https://projectname.ddev.local.

how to solve this

Version and configuration information:

- windows 10 education
- ddev `v1.7.1` installed by choco `choco install ddev`
- docker desktop `v2.0.0.3`

*Edits:*

- changed title
- add windows-10 tag
- typo

Comment: Could you edit the title to hint what the problem ended up being? Add windows on there?

Comment: Sure, I have used more or less your title in closed issues as a guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [problem](https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1566) is windows has 10 hosts max in `etc/hosts` and doesn't work any more after that.

The solution is `ddev remove --all && ddev hostname --remove-inactive`

Comment: As of ddev v1.8.0 ddev at least warns about this situation on `ddev start`